# How can I enhance a MouseOver on image script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover

I have written a small script. Here is the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kolxoznik1/MfLuU/3/

Everything works good, but I need to optimize it because in my opinion code isn't written as it should be. Like to hear what can be improved.

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sir, you have 8 questions and not marked any as answered. Reward us for trying to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid - that's why jsfiddle highlighted your last `div` tag.  Make sure you close your `img` tag and the closing anchor tag had the slash in the wrong place.

```
<a href="#"><img src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/cnn/2011/WORLD/europe/09/04/france.strauss.kahn.arrival/c1main.strauss.kahn.paris.jpg" alt="" title="" class="medium_photo right"/></a>
```

You can use chaining on your jQuery calls.  You should probably also use `find` so you only get the `.b` that is underneath the current `.a`

```
$(".a").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find('.b').show();
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find('.b').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jQuery's [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method.